# dplyr select is claiming that I have extra arguments that are not there

Tags: r, dplyr

```r
data <- tibble(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
data %>% select(x)
```

returns

```
Error: `...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `logical`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
```

I can not figure out what is causing this error.  I've tried reinstalling dplyr, restarting R, restarting the computer.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Running slang::last_error() gives

```r
<error/rlib_error_dots_nonempty>
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `logical`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
Backtrace:
  9. dplyr::select(., x)
 11. tidyselect::vars_select(tbl_vars(.data), !!!enquos(...))
 12. tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
 20. tidyselect:::vars_select_eval(...)
 21. tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
 22. tidyselect:::eval_c(expr, data_mask, context_mask)
 23. tidyselect:::reduce_sels(node, data_mask, context_mask, init = init)
 24. tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(init, data_mask, context_mask)
 25. tidyselect:::as_indices_sel_impl(...)
 26. tidyselect:::as_indices_impl(x, vars, strict = strict)
 27. vctrs::vec_as_subscript(x, logical = "error")
 28. ellipsis::check_dots_empty()
 29. ellipsis:::action_dots(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Comment: Can you show your `dplyr` version as I can't reproduce it

Comment: ✓ ggplot2 3.2.1            ✓ purrr   0.3.3       
✓ tibble  2.99.99.9014     ✓ dplyr   0.8.4       
✓ tidyr   1.0.2            ✓ stringr 1.4.0       
✓ readr   1.3.1            ✓ forcats 0.4.0

Comment: I have the dev version of `dplyr`  May be it is an issue with your version

Comment: installing the development version did cause the problem to stop.  Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem right after I installed a new package that resulted in many other packages being updated.  I think one of them got corrupted.  Installing the dev version of dplyr had no effect, nor did reinstalling the normal dplyr.

What ended up working for me was to reinstall all of the packages mentioned in the `rlang::last_error()` backtrace.

Comment: This worked. I removed `tibble`, `dplyr`, `vctrs` and a few others, and then used `install.packages(tidyverse)`.

Comment: This is what worked for me as well, it was also caused by installing a new package.

Answer (score 1):

I found many solutions pointing at a new installation, so I will suggest the programmatical solution I found for another dplyr verb: slice_max(.data, order_by, ...,  n)

I found the error you reported when I used:
data %>% slice_max(order_by = column_in_data, 10)

I corrected it by explicitly indicating the input name:
data %>% slice_max(order_by = column_in_data, n = 10)

Answer (score 0):

We can install the `devel` version of `dplyr` and it could solve the issue

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

Comment: Unfortunately `data %>% dplyr::select(x)` gives the same error.  I've added the output of `rlang::last_error()` to give more context

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing occur. Pretty much out of the blue. Happened with tidyr::separate, So it probably propagates from dplyr into other packages depending on it. Happened on code that had no issue running previously.

Also managed to solve it by installing the dev version of dplyr, but I find this a very tricky solution. :/

Comment: Could you please elaborate it.

Comment: Yea, I wish I had some idea of what caused it. My experience was very similar.  It just stopped working all of a sudden