# Top rows of count of a specific column in DF in R

Tags: r

This is my dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data

Ive been try to create a histogram for the most busiest ID's of a dataset.

So first I create the count

```
hostcount <-plyr::count(nycab2$host_id)
```

Then I try to use just the top 1-

```
hostcounttop <- head(arrange(hostcount, decreasing = TRUE), n = 10)
```

But I get this error

```
Error: Length of ordering vectors don't match data frame size
```

What's wrong with my code as the it's the same data frame size?

Answer (score 1):

`arrange` does not have `decreasing = TRUE` argument. You can use `desc` on the column name.

However, `plyr` has been retired and most of the functions are available in `dplyr`. You can do :

```
library(dplyr)
hostcounttop  <- nycab2 %>%  count(host_id) %>% slice_max(n, 1)
#If you have dplyr version < 1.0.0 use `top_n`.
#hostcounttop <- nycab2 %>%  count(host_id) %>% top_n(1, n)
```

---

In base R, we can do this as :

```
mat <- stack(table(nycab2$host_id))
mat <- mat[order(mat$values), ]
#to get top 10 values use tail
tail(mat, 10)
```

Comment: I tried your formula but for some reason it gives me this ```Error in count(., host_id) : object 'host_id' not found``` which makes no sense as the DF clearly has ```host_id```

Comment: Yes, I think your code is using `plyr::count`. Try using it with `dplyr::count` like this `nycab2 %>%  dplyr::count(host_id) `

Comment: ```hostcounttop  <- nycab2 %>%  dplyr::count(host_id) %>% slice_max(n, 1)```, tried this and now I get this error ```Error: `...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `..1`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?``` , So I ran ```rlang::last_error```, which gave me this. ```<error/rlib_error_dots_nonempty>
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `..1`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?```

Comment: Works fine with `mtcars` example for me: `mtcars %>% count(cyl) %>% slice_max(n, 1)`. Does the above work for you? Maybe you need to update the packages as few of these posts suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021210/dplyr-select-is-claiming-that-i-have-extra-arguments-that-are-not-there , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599249/why-am-i-getting-the-is-not-empty-error-mostly-when-using-pipe-and-basic

Comment: I noticed a lot of others have the same problem as me. Unfortunately nothing seems to be working in my case.  Is there any other method without the use of dplyr that can help?

Comment: Even the `mtcars` example above doesn't work for you? What is your `packageVersion('dplyr')` ? Mine is `‘1.0.1’`. I updated the post with base R answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. How do you check what the version is? As I am very new to R, some of these intricacies bypass me.

Comment: I included that code already in the above comment. `packageVersion('dplyr')`. Did you try the base R option? Did it work for you?

Comment: Oh yup. So my package is 1.0.2

Comment: @Vij Those links shared earlier suggest that there are other package dependencies which might impact this. Did you try the base R solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: Hey mate. Unfortunately nothing worked. And as I'm quite inept with R, I can't even explain what I've done wrong. I had to eventually use a long winded method of what I wanted. As below 
```hostcount1 <- plyr::count(nycab2$host_id)...
hostcounttop <- hostcount1[which(hostcount1$freq > 50),]...
hostcounttop$new <- hostcounttop$x...
head(hostcounttop)...
sort(hostcounttop$new)...
hostcounttop$new <- as.character(hostcounttop$new)...
ggplot(hostcounttop, aes(x = new,y = freq))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")```. ..Thanks for all your help though. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `order()` instead of arrange, and subsetting the dataframe using brackets?

E.g. assuming the problem isn't with your dataframe, try:

```
order(hostcount, decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]
```

You can change the 1:10 to get as many as you want.

Comment: Unfortunately instead of subetting it turned it into a value. I was trying to take the top 10 hosts and put it into histogram.

Comment: Could you post a very small portion of your dataset that we could use to play around with? I would try to troubleshoot why my solution doesn't work on my own computer, but I don't want to have to register for kaggle just to download the dataset, haha.

Comment: Sure. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Perhaps you could try updating your original post with the data?